# How to create new columns by dividing all columns in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, data-preprocessing

i'm having a trouble in my code. i just want to create new columns by dividing all columns / survival_time and after i need to add new columns as (clv_mean_xxx) to main dataframe.

[image]

here is my code.

```
list_ib = ['actor_masterylevel', 'churn_yn', 'old_value2_num', 'old_value3_num','old_value4_num', 'time']

for i in list_ib:
    for j in list_ib:
        if i == j:
            break
        else:
            df = df[i] * df['survival_time']
            df['clv_' + str(i) + '_' + str(j)] = df
```

Comment: Above you wrote you want to "dividing all columns / survival_time" then in your code you are multiplying effectively creating 4 extra copies of each new column ? Maybe you would like to specify what you actually want to do.

Comment: What exactly dont you understand? I think it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirement, this should work

```
for i in list_ib:
    df['clv_mean_'+i] = df[i]/df['survival_time']
```

Comment: I was getting another error cause of string type values. But that worked, thank you. I appreciated! :)